# How does Java EE app server manage libs?

Tags: jakarta-ee, classloader

Assume that there is few Java EE applications deployed on one Java EE server (vendor is meaningless, it may be Glassfish, JBoss, WebLogic, etc). Each app include the same library in deployed .war or .ear, for example: log4j.jar. (Yes, i know it's good to install one .jar in ext-lib directory on the server, sharing this to all apps, but in this case every one has own copy of log4j.jar).

Now, server is deploying all of those apps, running:

1) one version of log4j.jar (maybe deployed as first), sharing for other apps?

2) number of log4j instances for every deployed application, (consuming RAM as many times as number of deployed apps)?

What sentence is correct?

Answer (score 2):

It will generally be 2) (older versions JBoss used to do 1) i.e. share the classes between applications by default), but that's generally a good thing because it means that library access in one web-app cannot influence another.  In your specific example, it allows you to have different log configurations for each app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the application container will use a different classloader for each application. So it's probably the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Normally all jars you include in an application are visible only to the application, since each application has its own class path. So using the same library in more than one application results in more instances of the same library loaded in memory.
It's up to the developer to avoid this duplication, saving the library in a shared folder on the application server and not including it in the application archive.
If using maven, one can declare a dependent library as "provided" to have it not included in the deployment archive.
Unfortunately each application server has its own configuration for shared jars, for example Glassfish wants them in the `domain/lib/ext` folder.
This can be managed by configuring maven with profiles, one for each application server one wants to deploy on, and configuring for each profile a plugin to copy libraries into the proper folders.